# How do I use four familiars in battle?

Tags: blood-brothers

So I am currently around level 45 with my main character and I am working through the West Midlands Underground.

At the moment there is a PvP event going on which I am actively taking part in. However, sometimes when I select my opponent I notice that they have a set of 4 familiars to battle against. How can I get this too?

I have already unlocked a couple of additional formations, so my best guess is that at some point I will get a 4-man formation. If this is the case, when will I get my first 4-main formation, and what other formations are available? (Note: I think my latest formation I got was "Wave")

Also, can you get more than a 4-man formation? I remember last week there was a different kind of event which had some sort of boss battles (large enemies) that allowed me to field 6 of my familiars at once. Is this just an event specific formation perhaps?

Perhaps another interesting question: once I have access to a 4-man formation, are there any motivations for me to ever go back to a 3-man?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it will be a while before you acquire the the 4 man formation and longer before you get a 5 man formation. After the West Midlands, there's West Lowlands, then West Underworld, and then East Underworld. As you clear the 5 zone areas you gain different styles of formations. You will gain the first style of a 4 man formation once you get to the Abyss Gate in the West underworld (this is how I got mine). Basically you pass the first 5 zones in the West Underworld to get the first 4 man formation.

I have not reached the 5 man style formation since I am not done with the West Underworld. So I am not able to tell you exactly when you will get the 5 man formation. I don't know if there is a 6 man formation just in case your wondering. Most of my opponents have the 5 man formation, and that is as highest I have seen a formation get in a PvP (player vs player) battle.

The Crystal Caverns is the event you are talking about from last week. Unfortunately that 6 man formation only applied to that specific event.

Umm there isn't any motivation to back to the 3 man formation because...you can't. Once you get the 4 man formation there is no going back to the 3 man formation. And the same will apply when you get the 5 man formation. Hope this clears up things.

Comment: Great answer,.. again! My question may have had some correct information. I actually got the first 4-man formation last night, and when I posted this question I was already on the first part of West Underworld so it really didn't take me long to get it. I also noticed the lack of ability to revert back to a 3-man.

Comment: Rumour has it that the first 5-man formation comes after completing East Underworld. Once confirmed it might be worth somebody updating this answer

Answer (score 3):

You can change your formation. When the click to the BRANCH and change your characters, which one you want to put for lead there are 6 man in 1 branch, when you in the event, if you unlock 4, or 5 there is a blue DOT in each character before you batle, you can switch your character. I currently have 4 man formation in battle or PVP, but is events I have six.

Answer (score 3):

You get the 5 skein formation after completing zone 5 of the first stage of east underworld

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is leave one of the slots empty to have a 3 persons formation or click on the arrow to the left on formation screen

Comment: You cannot click on any arrow to go back to a 3-man formation. Once you have 4-man, that is it, until you get 5

Comment: Although see @wackysuperman's answer for clarification on leaving a slot (really a row within a formation) open.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you leave a slot open (both front and reserve) you will have a three-familiar formation, but with the perk of getting slightly more XP per battle, as you'll be splitting XP among fewer familiars.

Answer (score 1):

The six man formation is not really a formation, it is just your entire party attacking at the same time instead of just the first three. This is only available in raid boss events, and you can get four-man formations after you get to Abby's Gate or something in West Underworld after you complete zone 5. I just got it a few days ago but I do not know when you get the five-man though.